# Calling a popover for an invalid input on multiple inputs for one page with different messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

So far I have this which will call the same message for all inputs on the same page with this class if the field is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCalculation").click(function() {
    $(".checkCalc").each(function() {
      $val = $(this).val();
      if ($val === "") {      
        $(this).popover({
          content: "Enter the correct value."
        });
        $(this).popover('show');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

I am running Bootstrap too so I have a number of questions:

```
if ($val === "")
```

Works fine for empty values. But I would also like to add if any character that is **NOT** a number also needs to pop-up for this. Except the message I would like then is "You can only enter numbers in this field". Or something like that. I already have HTML validation working and I have turned off automatic pop-ups for validation.

The second thing, can I call the direction of the pop-over? I'd prefer the pop-over to occur underneath the input, however, I am not fussy, but I'd like to know how it is possible.

Third thing, I have seven input boxes on this page and so each is a little bit unique, do I have to do a separate `$(document).ready(function() {` for each input that has a unique message or can I chain together different classes to call a particular message?

Fourth thing, I would like the pop-over to disappear when either a correct value is entered or, if it is just easier, when they click in the input box with the error.

I am very new to JS so this is all a little above my paygrade right now, but once I have learned this I think I will be able to help many others in this situation. I am already pleased with finding the code to make pop-overs happen - little steps :)

Thanks - I always add a tick for correct answers!

A final thing, and this is about coding etiquette, on the same page I have plain JS, is it bad form to have JS and Query on the same .js file? Do I need to convert this all to JS?

Answer (score 0):

After much deliberation I found I could go with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCalculation").click(function() {
    $(".checkVelocity").each(function() {
      const val = $(this).val();
      if (isOpen(val) || val > 300) {
        $(this).popover({
          placement: "top",
          content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
          template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>' +
            '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" id="invalid-input3">' +
            '</i></div><div class="popover-content col-9">Enter the velocity of the car between 10 and 300 ms<sup>-1</sup>, kmh<sup>-1</sup> or mph.' +
            '</div></div>'
        });
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).popover("hide");
        });
        $('html, body').scrollTop($(".cardBodyVelocity").offset().top);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

This had the added advantage of allowing a scroll-to the invalid input.